# Conditional SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges

Tags: security, runwithelevatedprivileges

Is there a way to use *SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges* conditionally.
For example, assume that i have a code block, if some condition is met i want to run this code block in *SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges*, otherwise i want to run this code block without *SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a method with the VOID return (required by the delegate). Afterwards, use the if to determine your condition, and the actual method.

```
 //Run the MyElevatedFunctionCall function with elevated priviledges
       SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated elevatedCall = new SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated(MyElevatedFunctionCall);
```